# Windows Tesseract OCR getting scattered HOCR out put instead of clean standard format

Tags: windows, command-line, ocr, tesseract, hocr

A quick help is highly appreciated. I am extracting the text from the tiff image through tesseract-OCR.
The output I am looking for is.HOCR (HTML).
I am getting the perfect output in terms of content, but the format looks very unorganized.
But the same when I open with Notepad ++ it gives a clean format.

The windows command line is given below

```
Tesseract "Path\image.tiff" "Path\output" HOCR
```

need your help in getting the organised hocr format in notepad as enclosed

How do I get organized  hocr [image: output format in notepad] data when I open with notepad?
[image: The present output in Notepad] [image: the display of unorganised data in notepad ++]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in tesseract, but in notepad. Use some normal text editor like [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [context](https://www.contexteditor.org/).

Comment: Yes, I tried with context, and looks perfect. The reason I got doubt is few files are perfect on notepad and few are scattered.

Comment: Is there any additional code to specify to clean align in any text editor?